# Cannot create ECS Service via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I create the following CloudFormation template files to create ECS Cluster and TaskDefinition, Service but got an error.
What's wrong these settings?

1. When create ECS Service using the following templates, got `Please verify that the ECS service role being passed has the proper permissions`
2. When create the templates without a property `Role: !ImportValue "IAMRoleECSService"` , does not occur errors, but does not finish from `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS`

---

```
ECSApplicationService:
  Type: "AWS::ECS::Service"
  DependsOn:
    - "ECSApplicationCluster"
    - "ECSApplicationTaskDefinition"
  Properties:
    Cluster: !Ref "ECSApplicationCluster"
    DeploymentConfiguration:
      MaximumPercent: 100
      MinimumHealthyPercent: 50
    DesiredCount: 4
    LoadBalancers:
      - ContainerName: !Ref "ContainerAppName"
        ContainerPort: 80
        TargetGroupArn: !ImportValue "ALBTargetGroup"
    Role: !ImportValue "IAMRoleECSService"
    ServiceName: "ecs-application-service"
    TaskDefinition: !Ref "ECSApplicationTaskDefinition"

IAMRoleECSService:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
  Properties:
    RoleName: "ecs-service"
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Principal:
            Service:
              - "ecs.amazonaws.com"
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRole"
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: "ec2-management"
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Action:
                - "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress"
                - "ec2:Describe*"
              Resource: "*"
      - PolicyName: "alb-management"
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Action:
                - "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer"
                - "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets"
                - "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups"
                - "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth"
                - "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*"
                - "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer"
                - "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets"
              Resource: "*"
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
As of July 19th 2018, it is now possible to create a IAM Service-Linked Roles using CloudFormation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-servicelinkedrole.html.

```
   EcsServiceLinkedRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::ServiceLinkedRole"
    Properties:
      AWSServiceName: "ecs.amazonaws.com"
      Description: "Role to enable Amazon ECS to manage your cluster."
```

---

**OLD ANSWER:**
ECS now rely on a [Service-Linked Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using-service-linked-roles.html) instead of normal roles. Make sure you have created it for the account using:

`aws iam create-service-linked-role --aws-service-name ecs.amazonaws.com`

Then remove the `Role` parameter from your `IAMRoleECSService` as it's no longer needed.

Comment: Is it possible to name the service-linked role?

Comment: I'm afraid not, but it's not supposed to matter considering you never have to reference this role by its name.

Comment: @YohsukeInoda look at the update I posted, you can nom manage service linked role using CloudFormation, it's even possible to set a CustomSuffix so the name would be unique